# how to resize a image window when container is less than a certain width in css

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that's 1920 pixel wide. I want it to display centered and cropped in the browser window when it's width is greater than 1024 pixels. When the browser width is less than 1024, the image should be centered and cropped to 1024 pixels and then resized to the browser width.

I can't figure out how to do this, and haven't found any solutions on the internet yet. 
Can anyone tell me how to do this, or point me at examples?

Comment: did you try the css clip property?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what are you trying to do, BUT I think what are you looking for is:
`max-width`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit` property:

```
.image-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    > img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: 50% 50%;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be achieved using media queries. Following is just an example. Hope you can proceed with that.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

Here background color will be changed when you resize the browser and browser width is less than 480px.